# jQuery Sortable logic

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Using this idea, I have 4 slots per round (many rounds, paginated). When dragging from a list of people, I want to replace the placeholder and limit the number of items in the list to 4.
[image]

So, is it better to use a connected sortable list, or customize the draggable droppable plugins?

I can get the basics, but I'm having trouble making this feel right in that it just feels too much like jQuery-UI sortable list, and not dropping into the slot/replacing the selection-placeholder...

Advice?

Comment: provide on fiddle friend

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Geupm/7/ This is all I have at the moment...I've fooled with removing on drop, but can't get the replacement to work...

Comment: So if I drag Tom below Ten Points Pick #1 you want `Ten Points Pick #1` to dissappear and `Tom` to show up in its place?  Do you want `Tom` the orginal one on the left to dissapear?  etc..  I'm not sure everything you are trying to accomplish but I would recommend building it with just the droppable and draggable `ui's` if you are just replacing things. But if you have sub-menus and or you want to see the items moving into place while dragging..  Then sortable makes sense.. I guess I still don't have a good idea in my mind what your trying to accomplish.

Comment: The players-list needs to be static and clone. Any player should completely replace the "points" placeholder. Does this clarify?

Comment: Yeah. I'll post a fiddle to see if its what your looking for.

Comment: Something like: http://jsfiddle.net/Geupm/8/ ?

Comment: Yes! Except...the right-side items need to be replaceable and sortable still...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

```
  var sorting = false;
  var pickArray = [];
  $('.picks-group li').each(function(){
      pickArray.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.picks-group li').droppable({
      drop: function (event, ui) {
          if(!sorting)
              $(this).text(ui.helper.text()).addClass('done');
      }
  });
  $('#players-list li').draggable({
      helper: 'clone',
      revert: 'invalid'
  });
$('.picks-group').sortable({
     start: function (event, ui) {
         sorting = true;
      },
      stop: function (event, ui) {
          sorting = false;    
      },
      change: function (event, ui) {
          $(this).find('li').not('.ui-sortable-helper').each(function(index){
              if(!$(this).hasClass('done'))
                  $(this).text(pickArray[index]);
          });
      }
});
$('.picks-group li').mousedown(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('done'))
        return false;
});
```

Example:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Geupm/11/)

Comment: That's awesome, Trevor...Still two issues. 1) The Picks placeholder should not be sortable...and this adds another difficulty in that once you take something in position 2 and move to position 3 (on the sorted side), I need the placeholder to return...I'm working on my own fiddle with alternate code...I'll let you know if I get it figured out.

Comment: @KevinBrown Check my update.. I just tried to address the two issues you mentioned using my existing fiddle.

Comment: Nice, Trevor. I think I can work out the rest on my own.

Comment: Trevor, the only other thing I want to do is fire a css3 animation on start and stop...having trouble knowing how to apply to the cloned object on drag.

Comment: that looks good. Is it possible to call already made css animations? ie. the 'pulse' animation from animate.css